# Get element node count with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if I can explain this right...

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="myTD">aaa</td>
        <td class="myTD">bbb</td>
        <td class="myTD">ccc</td>
        <td class="myTD">ddd</td>
        <td class="myTD">eee</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Some jquery like this:

```
$('.myTD').on('click', function(e){
    //... do some here ...//
});
```

when I click on a TD I want the node count of the clicked td.

E.g. if I click on `ccc` I want to alert `3`

Is this possible in some way or do I have to explizit add an ID ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
$('.myTD').on('click', function(){
    alert( $(this).index() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="myTD">aaa</td>
        <td class="myTD">bbb</td>
        <td class="myTD">ccc</td>
        <td class="myTD">ddd</td>
        <td class="myTD">eee</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```